# BeautifulSoup - AttributeError when using find_all on multiple `table`s

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to build a web scraper (code below) but I am always getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wikipedia.py", line 11, in <module>
    for table in match.find_all('table'):
  File "/Users/claycrosby/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 2160, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

I've tried swapping `find` for `find_all` as per the message but it doesn't change the error that is returned. Further, there are multiple `table`s nested within the `vevent summary` which I initially find

I've tried multiple iterations of going directly from vevent summary to tr and I get the same error

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKLae.png)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020%E2%80%9321_Top_14_season'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
match = soup.find_all('.vevent summary')

#for table in match.find_all('table'):
for data in match.find_all('tbody'):
    for row in data.find('tr'):
        for cell in row.find('td'):
            print (cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', ''))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Beautiful Soup, use `find_all("div", {"class": "vevent"})` to search by class name. The error was referring to `match` which returns a list.

Try this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020%E2%80%9321_Top_14_season'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
match = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "vevent"})  # returns list

print('matches',len(match))

for m in match:
  for table in m.find_all('table'):
      for data in table.find_all('tbody'):
          for row in data.find_all('tr'):
              for cell in row.find_all('td'):
                  print (cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', ''))
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful, solved my issue. Thanks for bearing with a beginner style question

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import bs4 as bs

url_1 = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020%E2%80%9321_Top_14_season'
sauce_1  = urllib.request.urlopen(url_1).read()
soup_1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce_1, 'lxml')

for table in soup_1.find_all('table'):
    print(table.text)
```